# I want to know, what is happening on highlighted line?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to print this array `[1,2,3,4]` as a 2D array `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. This is the code. I am not getting these line

```
vector<int> aux(&original[i], &original[i+n]);
ans.push_back(aux);
```

how the syntax of 2D vector is working? Here is the function code?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> construct2DArray(vector<int>& original, int m, int n) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        int p = original.size();
        if(m*n != p)
            return ans;
    for(int i=0;i<p;i+=n){
            vector<int> aux(&original[i], &original[i+n]);
            ans.push_back(aux);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: [Constructor (5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Are you using leetcode to learn C++? If so don't (you may ask me why)

Comment: Good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date since C++ evolves and better techniques are added each release.

Comment: xaviour1504 did the answer clear things up or do you want me to explain anything in more detail?

Comment: yes I got it thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
vector<int> aux(&original[i], &original[i+n]);
```

is using the `vector` constructor that takes two *iterators*:

```cpp
template< class InputIt >
constexpr vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

and populates the new `vector` *as-if* by doing something similar to this:

```cpp
int* first = &original[i];
int* last = &original[i+n];
for(; first != last; ++first) aux.emplace_back(*first);
```

Note that `ans.push_back(aux);` should have been `ans.push_back(std::move(aux));` to not copy the whole `vector` but instead *move* it into `ans`.

Also note that creating the `aux` container is totally unnecessary. You can create it in-place directly in `ans` instead which saves the time of copying/moving `aux` into `ans`.

```cpp
ans.emplace_back(&original[i], &original[i+n]);
```